# SELENIUM PYTHON My script get stuck in line driver.get(url)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use ChromeDriver v92.0.4515.107, Chome Portable v92.0.4515.131, SOMETIME I get stuck after visit an url, the next line will never be executed, no time out, no error, I have to kill it by myself, and if I run it again, it still work normally, this is really annoying, please help me how to fix this.

```
profile = [p for p in range(10)] 
for i in range(len(profile)):
    
    user_data_path = r'F:\Bulk Profile\GoogleChromePortable\Data\profile'

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = r"F:\Bulk Profile\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe"
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222") 
    options.add_argument(f'''user-data-dir={user_data_path}''') 
    options.add_argument(f"profile-directory=Profile {profile[i]}") 

    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\minh7\OneDrive\Máy tính\chromedriver v92 for portable.exe", chrome_options=options) 
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('https://twitter.com') #Sometime It get stucked in this line until I kill it manually
    print('This Line Is Not Executed')
```